# Memory usage and execution speed of a PHP script

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I have the following two code. Which code is good in terms of performance?

```
$gd = $this->getDoctrine();
$em = $gd->getEntityManager();
$data = $gd->getRepository('MyB:MyC')->find...;
// update $data.
$em->persist($data);
$em->flush();
```

I want to know its memory usage and execution speed.

```
$data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyB:MyC')->find...;
// update $data.
$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->persist($data);
$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

Comment: I don't have any metrics for you but personally my code looks like the first one. It's better to read and easier to change.

Comment: no way of really saying that would be more than an educated guess.  You're going to have to use a tool such as the profiler in xdebug or functions such as memory_get_usage () to get some hard data.  In practice however, the difference is probably not going to be significant and using performance to favour one over the other will usually boil down to a [tag:micro-optimization].  You should write code to be correct and maintainable first, then worry about performance if it's demonstrably problematic.

Comment: @GordonM Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The former one will be faster is most cases, but eats up more memory.

tl;dr

Depends on how the underlying `getDoctrine()` works, the second method will at least add some method-calling overheads in execution.

If the methods do calculations and do not have any caching mechanism, you will also have to trace down the whole call stack for this.

There is always a tradeoff between memory footprint and performance overhead.

**EDIT**

Worse case: The latter will create an instance of some kind of underlying data, every single time you call a getter. This do not help in performance, even creates heap spikes.

Best case: All subsequence call to the getters are accessing the same object, which is in fact quite rare in DAO or SQL helpers, consumes the exact same memory as the first one just because there is a reference kept inside the parent object.

My suggestion in this case, use the first one.

Comment: "PHP uses a copy on write mechanism". So it won't use much memory for "$gd and $em", right? In the second case, even if the reference is taken from the function, the function will increase the execution time, right?

Comment: I haven't studied the symfony thing, the best I could do is kinda 'generic' answer. First statement is true on arrays, object instantiation depends on how the object is defined. And you are right on the second statement, try wrapping 1+1 in like thousands of functions and you'll likely see something in benchmarks.

Comment: I don't thing it is symfony specific. The methods just returning a reference. that is all ( I think)

Comment: Not entirely true. Some DAO implementations creates a new object on every query, as they follow the 'data object is immutable' rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out very easily

```
memory_get_peak_usage ()
```

See http://php.net/manual/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php